# Tableau and SSAS Tabular with greyed out dimensions

Tags: tableau-api, business-intelligence, ssas-tabular

I am currently working with Tableau and SSAS Tabular. Can somebody please help shed some light on Tableau behaviour:

When selecting a measure from the model some dimensions are greyed out. These dimensions are however connected to the measure source table in the data model. Why does Tableau show them greyed out and what can I do to correct this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

We have found that Tableau is not able to connect correctly to the SSAS tabular model when it is deployed to SSAS 2016 with compatibility level 1200. After converting the model to compatibility leve 1103 (SSAS 2014) and still deploying it to SSAS 2016 Tableau is now able to connect to the SSAS tabular model correctly.